# Pinterest Authetication - API method not found

Tags: authentication

I am using V5 pinterest API,

```
https://api.pinterest.com/oauth/?client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&redirect_uri=<REDIRECT_URI>&response_type=code&client_secret=<CLIENT_SECRET>
```

after this get request I getting below error message

```
{
    "status": "failure",
    "code": 11,
    "message": "API method not found.",
    "endpoint_name": null,
    "data": null
}
```

Any pointers will be helpful to get the successful authentication request to fetch the acess_token

Regards,
Rita

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/getting-started/authentication/), the endpoint should be,

```
https://www.pinterest.com/oauth/
```

So your request will be like this,

```
https://www.pinterest.com/oauth/?
client_id={YOUR_CLIENT_ID}&
redirect_uri={YOUR_REDIRECT_URI}&
response_type=code&
scope=boards:read,pins:read
```

Note that you need at least one scope in the request.

Comment: Thanks. in my case redirect_uri was not set at app level. its working now